# Linking two Classes without Inheritance

Tags: c#, accessor

This really may be a totally dumb question.

I have two classes in a COM library that I've been working on. There are more, but these two are relevant. I have a Report class and a Page class. The Report class has a List of Page classes.

```
public class Report
{
    private List<Page> PagesInReport;
}
```

The Page class has a list of LineItem classes that is private

```
public class Page
{
    private List<LineItem> LineItems;
}
```

Is there a way my Report class can access the Page class' LineItems without making the LineItem list completely public? I don't want users/developers to directly access the Page class' LineItems from VBA.

How can I link these two classes?

Comment: could you use the internal keyword to only allow types in the assembly access them? you could make accessor and setter methods?

Comment: Yup. That's what I went with. I just had a mental lapse and thought too complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the access modifier on `LineItems` `internal` instead of `private`.  Then, other classes in your assembly (i.e. your class library) can access it, but it cannot be accessed outside your assembly.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go crawl into a hole right now and sleep for days.